# How do I increase the speed of a large series of UPDATEs in mySQL vs SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have an application which I'm writing in Java with simple SQL, so no custom MySQL or SQL Server here - it might have to run on either. One data persist operation has to grab the data out of the DB, compare it with what has been submitted and then insert, update or delete accordingly.

I've improved the performance of the operation considerably by batching the JDBC calls.

So my **INSERTs** - I just call the `Statement.addBatch()` method for the whole data set to be inserted, and the JDBC driver creates

```
INSERT INTO data (parentId, seriesDate, valueDate, value) 
    VALUES (a,b,c,d),(a,b,e,f),(a,b,g,h)... etc
```

The **DELETEs** - I just delete the whole lot with

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE parentId = a AND seriesDate = b;
```

and I can re-insert them. (It may be better to take another approach by composing a big long

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE (parentId = 1 AND seriesDate = b) 
    OR (parentId = 2 AND seriesDate = c) 
    OR (parentId = 3 AND seriesDate = d)  ...
```

but that's not the issue here, my main problem is that the **UPDATEs** are really slow - twice as slow as the **INSERTs**

I get 1000 separate statements:

```
UPDATE data SET value = 4 
    WHERE parentId = 1 AND seriesDate = '' AND valueDate = '';
```

In SQL Server, the **UPDATEs** are just as quick as the **INSERTs**, but in MySQL I am seeing it run 10 x slower.

I am hoping I've forgotten some mutually compatible approach, or missed out on some JDBC connection configuration I need to adjust, maybe in conjunction with the number of items I'm putting in each batch.

**[UPDATE 2018-05-17]** Here's the requested DDL - and unfortunately I can't change this (yet) so any suggestions that involve schema changes won't help, at least not this year :(

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  parentId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  seriesDate DATE NOT NULL,
  valueDate DATE NOT NULL,
  value FLOAT NOT NULL,
  versionstamp INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  createdDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  last_modified DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT pk_data PRIMARY KEY (parentId, seriesDate, valueDate),
  CONSTRAINT fk_data_forecastid FOREIGN KEY (parentId)
    REFERENCES forecast (id)
) MAX_ROWS 222111000;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_data_update BEFORE UPDATE ON data
  FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.versionstamp = OLD.versionstamp + 1;

CREATE INDEX ix_data_seriesdate ON `data` (seriesDate);
```

The **INSERT**:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`parentId`, `valueDate`, `value`, `seriesDate`)
    VALUES (52031,'2010-04-20',1.12344,'2013-01-10')

EXPLAIN PLAN:
id: 1
select_type: INSERT
table: data
partitions:
type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ix_data_seriesdate
```

and the **UPDATE**:

```
UPDATE `data` SET `value` = -2367.0
    WHERE `parentId` = 52005 AND `seriesDate` = '2018-04-20' AND `valueDate` = '2000-02-11'

EXPLAIN PLAN:
id: 1
select_type: UPDATE
table: data
partitions: 
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ix_data_seriesdate
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 10
ref: const,const,const
rows: 1
filtered: 100
Extra: Using where
```

and the **DELETE**:

```
DELETE FROM `data` WHERE `parentId` = 52030 AND `seriesDate` = '2018-04-20'

EXPLAIN PLAN:
id: 1
select_type: DELETE
table: data
partitions: 
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ix_data_seriesdate
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 7
ref: const,const
rows: 1
filtered: 100
Extra: Using where
```

FYI 2 fields are updated automatically - `last_modified` by the `ON UPDATE` clause and `versionstamp` by the trigger (and again, I can't ditch that functionality).

Comment: Which one will you do most often?

Comment: Please share the table's DDL including the indexes, the real query and the execution plan.

Comment: OK done. I also discovered the UPDATEs in SQL Server are not affected by this issue - just mySQL.

Comment: *" simple SQL, so no custom MySQL or SQL Server here - it might have to run on either"* - Sure, you can use "vanilla" SQL to keep your code base simple, but if performance is truly important then you may have to consider using platform-specific features. You should be able to identify the type of back-end database from the `Connection` object you have, e.g., a `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection` or a `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection`

Comment: @GordThompson currently using the JDBC connection string to identify the database and customise the SQL in a wrapper around my connection & statement objects. Initially that was quick but I don't want to reinvent Hibernate :( It looks like I have narrowed the problem down to the JDBC driver, because the updates are faster than the inserts in SQL Server. I'll probably post another question with a more targetted subject.

Comment: @Adam - Oh!  In your other Question, you failed to mention the Trigger.  This _may_ be a big performance hit on the `UPDATE` !

Comment: @Adam - Is the `DELETE` multi-row?  (I don't see the 3rd column of the PK.)

Answer (score 2):

Ways I've found to improve UPDATE statements:

- use auxiliary tables (which could "batch" your updates)
- check for unnecessary triggers
- improve indexing (for the WHERE clause)
- OLAP or OLTP middle-man temp tables (they allow a batch of updates)

E.G.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempData ( 
  parentId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  seriesDate DATE NOT NULL,
  valueDate DATE NOT NULL,
  value FLOAT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TempData ( parentId, seriesDate, valueDate, value ) VALUES ( .... ), ( .... ), ( .... );

UPDATE
  data
SET
  value = #TempData.value
FROM
  #TempData
WHERE
  data.parentId = #TempData.parentId AND
  data.seriesDate = #TempData.seriesDate AND
  data.valueDate = #TempData.valueDate;
```

Comment: The triggers are not unnecessary :( and the indexing I think is good (willing to be proved wrong - I added the indexing to the question), but what do you mean about auxiliary tables and  batching?

Comment: I'm not sure I would have made the composite primary key, but an index across the parentId, seriesDate and valueDate is probably a good idea. What I mean by Auxiliary table is to create a side table that stores a type of data that is used often - like just a series of dates with date parts, or numbers from 0 to 1 million. Auxiliary might not help here, but you could use a temporary table like an OLTP: Create a temporary table that only stores value, parentID, seriesDate and valueDate. Populate that temp table first then use it for your update on the actual table.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you 100% on that but at this point I'm not going to touch the schema. Further down the line I will get the chance to normalise that `seriesDate` out of there, but not yet.

Comment: @Adam : Even without normalizing the data, you should be able to use the #TempData model. One word of caution about #Temp tables in general is that they can bloat your database_logs database over time, which will need to be addressed with either throwing disk space at it or a good maintenance plan. They also take on the COLLATE of the server, not the database you run the query on. These are just things to consider moving forward, but I think applying the #TempData as presented in the updated answer should benefit your performance. Let me know if that doesn't work out for you. Cheers!

Comment: The index for the `UPDATE` is the PK; can't get better than that.  ??

Comment: @Adam - Do _not_ normalize dates -- that only slows things down.  (1) In MySQL (at least), a `DATE` is internally stored as a 3-byte integer.  (2) The `JOIN` to use the date_id would be extra overhead.

Comment: @Paurian - MySQL 8.0 has non-logged temp tables in InnoDB.  (After all, if there is a crash, you will start over, rebuilding the temp table.  So why log it?)