# MariaDB JDBC driver not batching updates efficiently vs SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jdbc, mariadb

I benchmarked the performance of an insert/update/delete routine in my app which I am porting from SQL Server to MariaDB.

- Java 1.8 on local Win10 workstation with i7 2.80GHz CPU + 16GB RAM
- JDBC org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.2.4
- 10.2.12-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server on AWS

The benchmark fires off 50,000 inserts, the same updates and deletes.

SQL Server via the net.sourceforge.jtds JDBC driver handles them all in under 1 sec.

MariaDB with the MariaDB-java-client driver does the inserts faster, but the updates (and the deletes) are much slower at 3.5 secs.

The schema is the same in both databases, and I assume since the inserts in MariaDB are fast, this probably rules out an indexing issue or a server misconfiguration.

I have tried multiple variations for the JDBC connection string, ending up with this as the fastest:

```
  ?verifyServerCertificate=true\
  &useSSL=true\
  &requireSSL=true\
  &allowMultiQueries=true\
  &cachePrepStmts=true\
  &cacheResultSetMetadata=true\
  &cacheServerConfiguration=true\
  &elideSetAutoCommits=true\
  &maintainTimeStats=false\
  &prepStmtCacheSize=50000\
  &prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=204800\
  &rewriteBatchedStatements=false\
  &useBatchMultiSend=true\
  &useBatchMultiSendNumber=50000\
  &useBulkStmts=true\
  &useLocalSessionState=true\
  &useLocalTransactionState=true\
  &useServerPrepStmts=true
```

The performance in mysql and with the mysql-connectorj was worse in all cases than mariadb.

I've been looking at this for a week now and am thinking of employing the work-arounds suggested in my earlier question [How do I increase the speed of a large series of UPDATEs in mySQL vs SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380671/how-do-i-increase-the-speed-of-a-large-series-of-updates-in-mysql-vs-sql-server)

Just in case it might be a server misconfiguration, here's what I've got for the key variables:

```
key_buffer_size                16MB
innodb_buffer_pool_size        24GB (mem 30GB)
innodb_log_file_size           134MB
innodb_log_buffer_size         8MB
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit 0
max_allowed_packet             16MB
```

My 50,000 writes are only tiny amounts of data - approx 2MB. But with the SQL syntax, this is presumably 10 times greater when it goes over the JDBC connection - is that correct?

Here's the SQL and explain plans:

```
Describe `data`
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| parentId      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                               |
| modifiedDate  | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                               |
| valueDate     | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                               |
| value         | float            | NO   |     | NULL                |                               |
| versionstamp  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1                   |                               |
| createdDate   | datetime         | YES  |     | current_timestamp() |                               |
| last_modified | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL                | on update current_timestamp() |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+

INSERT INTO `data` (`value`, `parentId`, `modifiedDate`, `valueDate`) VALUES (4853.16314229298,52054,'20-Apr-18','28-Dec-18')

+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | INSERT      | data  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+



UPDATE `data` SET `value` = 4853.16314229298 WHERE `parentId` = 52054 AND `modifiedDate` = '20-Apr-18' AND `valueDate` = '28-Dec-18'

+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | data  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 10      | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+


DELETE FROM `data` WHERE `parentId` = 52054 AND `modifiedDate` = '20-Apr-18' AND `valueDate` = '29-Jan-16'

+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | data  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 10      | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

**[UPDATE]**

JDBC Usage - this is a pared-down version so excuse any egregious mistakes:

```java
    final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                 "UPDATE data SET value = ? " +
                         "WHERE parentId = ? " +
                         "AND modifiedDate = ? " +
                         "AND valueDate = ? ")) {
        // timeSeries is a list of 50,000 data points
        Arrays.stream(timeSeries)
                .forEach(ts -> {
            try {
                statement.setDouble(1, value);
                statement.setLong(2, parentId);
                statement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(
                        modifiedDate.getTime()));
                statement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(
                        valueDate.getTime()));
                statement.addBatch();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Bad batch statement handling", e);
            }
        });
        int[] results = statement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
```

I also have some data from the general_log showing the incoming JDBC calls, and it looks pretty basic - a 'prepare' call to set up the statement, and then individual updates.

This is what surprises me - there seems to be no batching:

```
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Query   set autocommit=0
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Prepare UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Execute UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Execute UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Execute UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Execute UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
13/06/2018 15:09    service_user_t[service_user_t] @  [9.177.2.31]  75954   298206495   Execute UPDATE `data` SET `value` = ? WHERE `parentId` = ? AND `modifiedDate` = ? AND `valueDate` = ?
etc
etc
```

Comment: Exactly what is your question? SQL Server is a different beast compared to MySQL or MariaDB, so performance differences can be expected. It is unlikely there is a magical fix that will bring the performance on-par with SQL Server. So, what do you want to achieve with this question?

Comment: There is no guarantee that either one will be faster/slower/the same for any given operation.

Comment: 3 to 5 times slower on one particular operation? I'm porting from SQL Server to MariaDB. I can't give my clients something that is slower! @MarkRotteveel are you saying you see nothing obviously wrong?

Comment: And if it does by chance all look fine, are there no obvious reasons to explain it?

Comment: Batching is complicated, and performance can vary wildly between implementations (eg because some don't support real batching and simulate it), performance of database systems themselves vary wildly (and usually commercial database systems are extensively tuned for high performance compared to open source offerings). I simply don't expect anyone will be able to give you the silver bullet for performance.

Comment: Just to be sure, you use PrepareStatment (like "INSERT INTO `data` (`value`, `parentId`, `modifiedDate`, `valueDate`) VALUES (?,?,?)" and passing the parameters) ?

Comment: Are you running your benchmark on local server, or on remote one?  Do you mix updates and deletes in your batch, or send them as separate batches? Are you using the same prepared statement for all updates in a batch, if you do not mix it with delete?

Comment: @Adam - How did you get `'20-Apr-18'` to work as a `DATE` in MySQL??  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Adam - How did you "batch" the operations?  Single transaction?  Single statement?

Comment: @Adam -- Benchmarking is not an easy task.

Comment: I'm not Adam, but is a JDBC batch :) Implementing this is left to driver, and there are a lot of tricks - protocol pipelining, semicolon separated statements, converting many inserts to multiinsert, and special MariaDB BULK extensions for the protocol.

Comment: @RickJames that SQL is from p6spy so it's just randomly formatted logging! I've added the Java algorithm and some of the general log. Plus I added my platform and software versions at the top.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub - I've measured multiinsert in several different situations -- typically about 10x speedup.  I suspect the other tricks are not that spectacular.

Comment: @Adam - "real" data has subtle patterns that may influence performance.  "Random" data may be the slowest -- for example, jumping around in indexes more.

Comment: So from the evidence in the general log, the UPDATE calls are not really being batched. Correct me if I'm wrong it looks pretty conclusive that the SQL Server/JTDS JDBC driver is just plain outstanding at doing UPDATEs.

Answer (score 0):

add "begin" and "commit" statements between some of the rows in your batch.
or start transaction before the batch, and commit after.
That will be a lot faster, than thousands of  individual statements.

If you only do inserts, rewriteBatchStatements=true should speed it up considerably, without transaction. Also you may also increase the max_packet_size to 1GB, this will do more batching, maybe your whole batch will be transformed to 1 very large multi-insert.

Comment: Primarily this is meant to be one transaction. I'll adjust the max_packet_size. Since `rewriteBatchStatements` is only for inserts, it's not going to help with updates, but there is also `useBatchMultiSend`, `allowMultiQueries` and others, but the docs don't mention if they apply to updates. Probably not. I've just noticed `useCompression` which might help.

Comment: With JDBC you should really not be manually starting and committing transactions. That should be handled by the JDBC driver (if you need to commit, then you should use `connection.commit()`, transactions will be started automatically when needed).

Comment: The question is specifically about MySQL-compliant drivers,  I happen to know MySQL dialect, and recall how the driver was written, too (I contributed to it), so can I answer the things I know first? (not what JDBC drivers should or should not do)

Comment: So, @Adam, one transaction is the most powerful optimization. You need to start it outside of the batch, with autocommit manipulation if you want to be JDBC compliant, or you can just /COMMIT statements anywhere in the batch if you do not use returned generated ids, this should be fine with all MySQL drivers.  You might optimize DELETEs if they go into the same table, into a single statement. But manually : "DELETE FROM <table> where <cond1>; DELETE FROM table where <cond2>" is equivalent to DELETE FROM table WHERE ((cond1) OR (cond2)). The driver does not have this optimization yet.

Comment: The compression is tricky, it compressed on the packet level. If you do not send large statements, and I believe you don't, and do you receive large results (you do not do either, with updates), it won't help at all.useBatchMultiSend, allowMultiQueries apply to all statements, so use them. The do similar things -  useBatchMultiSend does protocol pipelining (also can do prepared statements), allowMultiQueries sends batches in single query , semicolon separated

Comment: you may also try server-side prepared statements, useBatchMultiSend, and PreparedStatement.addBatch() . This may speed up a little, but not too much, within 20% I'd guess.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub I'm using `PreparedStatement.addBatch()` and I have `Connection.setAutoCommit(false)` because the operation has to be atomic. Are you really suggesting I give up transactionality for this? In that case I would have to code up a clean-up algorithm to extract the committed data on error.

Comment: No. I'm suggesting to have transactionality. If you already have,  that's correct and good, it spares Innodb a lot of transaction management. I also noticed there is a unconventional format for datetime you use. usually it is something like '2018-05-23 18.54:07' or similar. I'm surprised it works even :)

Comment: Actually, to me it looks like you probably have the optimal configuration, JDBC-side, with server-side prepared statements, pipelining, and transaction. The rest must be Innodb engine.  If you can share your benchmark driver somewhere, that'd be interesting to look at, and perhaps there is some Innodb parameter that would help.

Comment: 50K rows in a transaction _may_ stress the redo log and lead to slowing things down some.  I would use batches of 1K rows (unless there is a need to do all 50K at once).

Comment: Need for `COMMIT`??  In MySQL, it depends on the setting of `autocommit` !

Comment: @Adam - Turn on the "General log" in MySQL to capture what the driver sends through.  Then present us a sample (not 50K lines) of it.  Then we can nit pick whether the driver is adding things to slow it down.

Comment: initial state of autocommit is on (as by JDBC spec). the driver would set it on for the session if it was "off" globally

Comment: Although I truncated the general log severely to post a sample in my question, the only stuff that I have left out is UPDATE executes.